# Making a Tkinter Listbox with Scrolll

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

I'm currently trying to make a Listbox with a Scroll bar on the side appear on my Tkinter Window. I can't figure out how to make the Scrollbar size the same size as my listbox. Heres my code:

```
global R3
global lb

R3 = Tk()
gg = "white"
g = "blue"
R3.geometry('720x720')
R3.title(username + " Dropbox")
R3.resizable(width=False, height=False)
logoutbt = Button(R3, text="Logout", width=10, height=2, bg=g, fg=gg, font="5", relief=RAISED, overrelief=RIDGE, command=rectologout)
upload = Button(R3, text="Upload", width=10, height=2, bg=g, fg=gg, font="5", relief=RAISED, overrelief=RIDGE, command=rectoupload)
logoutbt.place(x=220, y=500)
upload.place(x=480, y=500)
button1 = Button(R3, text='Receive file', width=10, height=2, bg=g, fg=gg, font="5", relief=RAISED, overrelief=RIDGE,command = get_file)

lb = Listbox(R3, height=6,width = 15)
s.send("RETREIVEA-"+username)
file_list = s.recv(1024).split("-")
if file_list == [""]:
    button1.config(state = DISABLED)
for file in file_list:
    lb.insert("end", file)
yscroll = Scrollbar(R3, orient=VERTICAL)
lb['yscrollcommand'] = yscroll.set
yscroll['command'] = lb.yview
lb.place(x=280,y=200)
yscroll.place(x=370,y=200)
button1.place(x=400, y=200)
R3.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: This code doesn't run, it has many missing pieces. Please read about how to create a [mcve]. Also, you should seriously consider _not_ using `place`. `grid` and `pack` yield much better results for 99.9% of all tkinter programs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Your code lacks imports and references non-initialized objects / variables / functions.

How to achieve what you want?

Either use `grid` instead of `place` or pass height parameters to `lb.place(..., height=<whatever you want>)` and `yscroll.place(..., height=<whatever you want>)`